# Can I target an Android App at 5" screens and larger

Tags: android, google-play, filtering, screen-size, amazon-appstore

I am pretty sure I know the answer to this but will ask anyway. I have apps on Google Play and Amazon Apps Store so am looking for an answer that works for both. In these app stores apps can be filtered by screen size rather crudely as Small, Normal, Large and XLarge. We now have a number of 5" and 6" devices which are likely to be categorised as Normal. I have an app that would work okay on such a device but not on smaller Normal devices. Is there any way of targeting just devices >= 5" on these app stores?